# SpriteKit Gesture Issue

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I've been trying to implement a tile system similar to megaman battle network into this tactics/puzzle game. However, I can not seem to get the swipe gestures to move the sprite the desired distance.

Instead, the gestures end up moving the sprite to the bottom left of the view. In that corner, the gestures still seem don't seem to operate as configured.

Why does the sprite shift to the bottom left?

Here's the code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var mageNodeOne: Mage?

//Swipe gesture handlers
func swipedRight(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    mageNodeOne!.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x + 115, self.position.y)
    println("swiped right")
}

func swipedLeft(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    mageNodeOne!.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x - 115, self.position.y)
    println("swiped left")
}

func swipedUp(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    mageNodeOne!.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x, self.position.y + 220)
    println("swiped up")
}

func swipedDown(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    mageNodeOne!.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x, self.position.y - 220)
    println("swiped down")
}

//Scene Setup
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    // Add gesture recognizers to view
    let swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedRight:"))
    swipeRight.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedLeft:"))
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeUp:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedUp:"))
    swipeUp.direction = .Up
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

    let swipeDown:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedDown:"))
    swipeDown.direction = .Down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

    // Add tiles to view
    var tileSpacerOne = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "TileSpacer")
    tileSpacerOne.position = CGPoint(x: 508, y: 388)
    tileSpacerOne.zPosition = -1
    self.addChild(tileSpacerOne)

    var tileOne = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "TileExampleOne")
    tileOne.position = CGPoint(x: 350, y: 608)
    self.addChild(tileOne)

    var tileTwo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "TileExampleOne")
    tileTwo.position = CGPoint(x: 350, y: 388)
    self.addChild(tileTwo)

    var tileThree = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "TileExampleOne")
    tileThree.position = CGPoint(x: 350, y: 168)
    self.addChild(tileThree)

    var tileFour = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "TileExampleOne")
    tileFour.position = CGPoint(x: 665, y: 608)
    self.addChild(tileFour)

    var tileFive = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "TileExampleOne")
    tileFive.position = CGPoint(x: 665, y: 388)
    self.addChild(tileFive)

    var tileSix = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "TileExampleOne")
    tileSix.position = CGPoint(x: 665, y: 168)
    self.addChild(tileSix)

    // Add mage to view
    mageNodeOne = Mage(imageNamed: "MageOne")
    mageNodeOne!.position = CGPointMake(667,475.5)
    addChild(mageNodeOne!)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you moving the sprite to the location of `self` + 115 as opposed to the `mageNodeOne's` current location + 115.

Example:

```
 CGPointMake(self.position.x + 115, self.position.y)
```

Should be

```
 CGPointMake(mageNodeOne.position.x + 115, mageNodeOne.position.y)
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! I can't believe I didn't think to do that. I guess "self" references the view or the gesture recognizer itself?

Comment: sender would be the gesture since it is passed as a parameter. self references the instance of the class you are in.

Comment: So in this case, GameScene would be self. sender would be your gesture recognizer that called the method.